# how to reverse AJAX on HTML contenteditable DIV going to mySQL DB with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, contenteditable, reverse-ajax

Below you will find a link to my contenteditable DIV page, appropriately titled ce.php:

http://stateofdebate.com/ce.php

My desire from this question is to find an answer to how I can use Comet/reverse AJAX to immediately update the text on the page for all users when the text is changed. CURRENTLY, it is saved to my mySQL database, and the text is only updated when other users refresh the page.

Please do not give vague answers like "use WebSocket" or "use node.js". I have asked a question already similar to this and gotten those kind of answers. To get a vote or check from me, I need either complete answers or links to tutorials.

I feel like this, although a specific question with specific code, could help a lot of people with similar questions, if answered throughly and correctly.

Here is my complete code:

CE.PHP

```
<!doctype html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Gazpo.com - HTML5 Inline text editing and saving </title>


<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif' rel='stylesheet'      
type='text/css'>
<style>
body {      
font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
color:#333333;
font-size:13px;
}

h1{
font-family: 'Droid Serif', Georgia, Times, serif;
font-size: 28px;        
}

a{
color: #0071D8;
text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}

:focus {
outline: 0;
}

#wrap{
width: 500px;
margin:0 auto;              
overflow:auto;      
}

#content{
background: #f7f7f7;
border-radius: 10px;
}

#editable {     
padding: 10px;      
}

#status{
display:none; 
margin-bottom:15px; 
padding:5px 10px; 
border-radius:5px;
}

.success{
background: #B6D96C;
}

.error{
background: #ffc5cf; 
}

#footer{
margin-top:15px;
text-align: center;
}

#save{  
display: none;
margin: 5px 10px 10px;      
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;    
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font: 12px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight:700;    
padding: 5px 10px;  
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px; 
color: #606060;
border: solid 1px #b7b7b7;  
background: #fff;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#ededed));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fff,  #ededed);
filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff',    
endColorstr='#ededed');
}   

#save:hover
{
background: #ededed;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#dcdcdc));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fff,  #dcdcdc);
filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff',   
endColorstr='#dcdcdc');
}

</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"   
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#save").click(function (e) {         
    var content = $('#editable').html();    

    $.ajax({
        url: 'save.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
        content: content
        },              
        success:function (data) {

            if (data == '1')
            {
                $("#status")
                .addClass("success")
                .html("Data saved successfully")
                .fadeIn('fast')
                .delay(3000)
                .fadeOut('slow');   
            }
            else
            {
                $("#status")
                .addClass("error")
                .html("An error occured, the data could not be saved")
                .fadeIn('fast')
                .delay(3000)
                .fadeOut('slow');   
            }
        }
    });   

});

$("#editable").click(function (e) {
    $("#save").show();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function() {
    $("#save").hide();  
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<h1><a href="http://gazpo.com/2011/09/contenteditable/" > HTML5 Inline text editing and   
saving </a></h1>

<h4>The demo to edit the data with html5 <i>contentEditable</i>, and saving the changes   
to database with PHP and jQuery.</h4>

<div id="status"></div>

<div id="content">

<div id="editable" contentEditable="true">
<?php
    //get data from database.
    include("db.php");
    $sql = mysql_query("select text from content where element_id='1'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);         
    echo $row['text'];
?>      
</div>  

<button id="save">Save</button>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<a href="http://gazpo.com/">Tutorial by gazpo.com</a> 
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

SAVE.PHP

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$content = $_POST['content']; //get posted data
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($content);  //escape string 
$sql = "UPDATE content SET text = '$content' WHERE element_id = '1' ";
if (mysql_query($sql))
{
echo 1;
}
?>
```

DB.PHP

```
<?php
//database connection
mysql_connect("test.test00.com:2400", "first_testuser", "pw") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("jorgea_testdb") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

EDIT: still looking for an answer!
EDIT: deleting old question and creating new one in attempt to find someone who can answer this....

Comment: You answered your own question. you need comet/longpolling/websockets for this. Your server can **NOT** reach out and push content to users unless those users are maintaining an open connection to your server. And yes, it's a vague answer. We're not here to do your job for you. YOU write some comet code, and then we can try help fix it.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to modify the code I have compiled (see above). Thanks, Marc.

Comment: You can try a periodic Ajax call to check whether things are changed in your database. If so, replace it. Mind that a high update frequency (or a lot of users) will cause a high server load.

Comment: Thank you, Pieter. To my understanding, this is what Facebook originally did? But at some point they had to completely redo it so it would be more scalable?

Comment: In regards to your last comment: yes, that is how they had it originally. But, because most browers only allow a maximum of 2 HTTPD connections, users were getting throttled hard with 1 concurrent connection always open, and facebook would timeout and crash. This was changed to utilize `node.js` to push the data to the browser without destroying one of the HTTPD threads.

Comment: So what I should take away from this is that node.js is like .js Jesus?

Answer (score 0):

I refresh simply from the database using onBlur in the DIV. I needed it, as I have the background colour changing depending on the content of the field.

```
<DIV id='field_name' 'true'contenteditable='true' onBlur='location.reload(true);'>This text is editable</DIV>
```